# Form data is hashed in CakeRequest after upgrade to cakephp2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3

I just recently performed an upgrade from cakephp 1.3 to 2.06. However when I attempt to access form data in my controller, the data is hashed like so:

```
2015-10-15 08:43:57 Error: CakeRequest Object
(
[params] => Array
    (
        [plugin] => 
        [controller] => custom_users
        [action] => ajax_login
        [named] => Array
            (
            )

        [pass] => Array
            (
            )

        [isAjax] => 1
    )

[data] => e1fe8b4c1724c30148e306708f27b30909f23d45
```

I checked that the form is correctly formed on the front end. 
The documentation indicates that I should be able to access my data this way, but for some reason this behaviour is happening in stead. Any ideas?

I've added the trace I get when I try and submit the form:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/academy/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php on line 92

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/academy/lib/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php on line 456

Warning: Illegal string offset 'CustomUser' in /var/www/html/academy/app/Controller/CustomUsersController.php on line 569

Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in /var/www/html/academy/app/Controller/CustomUsersController.php on line 569

Warning: Illegal string offset 'CustomUser' in /var/www/html/academy/app/Controller/CustomUsersController.php on line 570

Warning: Illegal string offset 'password' in /var/www/html/academy/app/Controller/CustomUsersController.php on line 570

Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array in /var/www/html/academy/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php on line 92

Fatal error: Call to undefined method CustomAuthComponent::getModel() in /var/www/html/academy/app/Controller/Component/CustomAuthComponent.php on line 242
```

Comment: This is not the usual behavior, I upgraded a whole project from 1.3 to 2 some months ago and nothing of this occured. Anything in your app controller or any plugin/component that might be responsible for this? Also, check your beforeFilter callbacks.

Comment: @MonkeyKing that was helpful. I am at least able to confirm the data in the beforeFilter is not hashed.

Comment: @MonkeyKing do you mean the Security component?

Comment: `to 2.06` that version doesn't exist, what version are you _actually_ upgrading to? in 2.6.0 [the line with an error is a comment](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.0/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L92), in 2.0.6 [that line is a closing brace](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.6/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L92). Are you looking at the lines of code generating errors to understand what the root cause is (you should be)? Either way that's an odd version to upgrade to, the latest 2.x release is what you should upgrade to.

Comment: @user1658296 for example the Security component. Does it work without? Then you are a step forward in debugging.

Comment: There is also a problem with your CustomAuthComponent as you can see in the error log. You might have to upgrade this to CakePHP 2 as well.

Comment: Did you follow these guidelines? "When using the Security Component you must use the FormHelper to create your forms. In addition, you must not override any of the fields’ “name” attributes. The Security Component looks for certain indicators that are created and managed by the FormHelper (especially those created in create() and end()). Dynamically altering the fields that are submitted in a POST request (e.g. disabling, deleting or creating new fields via JavaScript) is likely to trigger a black-holing of the request. See the $validatePost or $disabledFields configuration parameters."